# Angularfire forEach key returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have some data

```
{
    "projects" : [
        {
            "projectName" : "Test Project 1",
            "dueDate" : "20/05/2014",
            "owner" : "Test owners 1",
            "categories" : [
                "JavaScript",
                "HTML",
                "CSS"
            ],
            "open" : true,
            "tasks" : [
                {
                    "taskName" : "Test task 1",
                    "targetDate" : "02/04/2014",
                    "categories" : [
                        "JavaScript",
                        "HTML",
                        "CSS"
                    ],
                    "open" : true
                },
                {
                    "taskName" : "Test task 2",
                    "targetDate" : "10/04/2014",
                    "categories" : [
                        "JavaScript",
                        "HTML"
                    ],
                    "open" : true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "projectName" : "Test Project 2",
            "dueDate" : "12/07/2014",
            "owner" : "Test owners 2",
            "categories" : [
                "JavaScript",
                "HTML",
                "CSS"
            ],
            "open" : true,
            "tasks" : [
                {
                    "taskName" : "Test task 1",
                    "targetDate" : "13/05/2014",
                    "categories" : [
                        "HTML",
                        "CSS"
                    ],
                    "open" : true
                },
                {
                    "taskName" : "Test task 2",
                    "targetDate" : "03/06/2014",
                    "categories" : [
                        "JavaScript"
                    ],
                    "open" : true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

then I have a simple controller that is trying to output the object contained in each array index

```
TM.factories.getData = function(){
    var getProjects = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/projects");
    return getProjects;
};

TM.controllers = {};

TM.controllers.overviewCtrl = function($scope,$firebase){
    var taskArr = [];
    $scope.projectList =  $firebase(TM.factories.getData());
    $scope.projectList.$on("loaded", function() {
        $scope.projectList.$getIndex().forEach(function(key,i) {
            console.log($scope.projectList[key]);
        });
    });
};
```

Don't worry about how it's laid out I'm experimenting with writing it in different ways and it's very early dev work.

The question is why am I getting **undefined** when using "key" or "i"? if I console log just "key" or "i" I get 0,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
TM.controllers.overviewCtrl = function($scope,$firebase){
    var taskArr = [];
    $scope.projectList =  $firebase(TM.factories.getData());
    $scope.projectList.$on("loaded", function(projectList) {
        projectList.$getIndex().forEach(function(value,key) {
            console.log(projectList[key]);
        });
    });
};
```